Coloring values in table on the website with jQuery
I have a website where values are given in a table. I would like them to be colored based on the numbers. I used JavaScript code, but it seems to work correctly for <div> and <p>, but not correctly for <td>. What am I doing wrong?


$(document).ready(function() {
  var mc = {
    '0-19': 'red',
    '20-59': 'orange',
    '60-100': 'green'
  };

  function between(x, min, max) {
    return x >= min && x <= max;
  }

  var dc;
  var first;
  var second;
  var th;

  $('td').each(function(index) {
    th = $(this);
    dc = parseInt($(this).attr('data-rawvalue'), 10);

    $.each(mc, function(name, value) {
      first = parseInt(name.split('-')[0], 10);
      second = parseInt(name.split('-')[1], 10);

      console.log(between(dc, first, second));

      if (between(dc, first, second)) {
        th.addClass(value);
      }
    });
  });
});
.red {
  color: red
}

.orange {
  color: orange
}

.green {
  color: green
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<td class="listViewEntryValue" data-name="cf_1104" title="57" data-rawvalue="57" data-field-type="integer">
  <span class="fieldValue">
        <span class="value">
            <span align="right">57</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</td>



I would like the numerical values in the table to be colored based on the number.

Please note that you're using jQuery not plain JS.

You do not have a table. You have a single TD
jQuery is currently not finding that td.
Also you have too many </span>
If you wrap it in a table it works using jQuery, also in v2.2.4


const mc = {
  '0-19': 'red',
  '20-59': 'orange',
  '60-100': 'green'
};

const between = (x, min, max) => x >= min && x <= max;

$(function() {

  $('td').each(function() {
    let td = $(this);
    let dc = parseInt($(this).attr('data-rawvalue'), 10);
    $.each(mc, function(name, value) {
      let first = parseInt(name.split('-')[0], 10);
      let second = parseInt(name.split('-')[1], 10);

      console.log(between(dc, first, second));

      if (between(dc, first, second)) {
        td.addClass(value);
      }
    });
  });
});
.red {
  color: red
}

.orange {
  color: orange
}

.green {
  color: green
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="listViewEntryValue" data-name="cf_1104" title="57" data-rawvalue="57" data-field-type="integer">
        <span class="fieldValue">
          <span class="value">
            <span align="right">57</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



Plain JS version


const mc = {
  '0-19': 'red',
  '20-59': 'orange',
  '60-100': 'green'
};

const between = (x, min, max) => +x >= min && +x <= max; // note I moved the casting to number here

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(ele => {
    let dc = +ele.dataset.rawvalue;
    Object.entries(mc).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      let [first, second] = key.split('-');
      if (between(dc, first, second)) {
        ele.classList.add(value);
      }
    });
  });
});
.red {
  color: red
}

.orange {
  color: orange
}

.green {
  color: green
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="listViewEntryValue" data-name="cf_1104" title="57" data-rawvalue="57" data-field-type="integer">
        <span class="fieldValue">
          <span class="value">
            <span align="right">57</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="listViewEntryValue" data-name="cf_1105" title="67" data-rawvalue="67" data-field-type="integer">
        <span class="fieldValue">
          <span class="value">
            <span align="right">67</span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Thanks, guys, but it's still not working. Now I just noticed that the version of jQuery you linked is 3.7.1, while my version is 2.2.4. I'm trying to implement this on vTiger 8.2.0, and upgrading jQuery is not an option. I'll probably give up on this coloring unless there's a simple solution to this problem without needing to upgrade jQuery. Thanks again.

So I changed the jQuery version and as you can see I ALSO posted a plain JS version. Either will work on a normal browser. I do not know what vTiger does or can do (limitations on DOM).
